# How to run SQLite query between 2 dates in xamarin forms cross platform

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

i have a database that stores data on jobs. i want to pull a list of jobs from the database between 2 dates. what would be an appropriate command to achieve that goal? please and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FetFrumos example, i was able to modify my commands to make it work.

```
public class Job
{
    .........
    DateTime DatePerformed {get; set;}
    .........
}

void SelectFromDateRange ()
{
    DateTime fromDate;
    DateTime toDate;

    var jobsBetweenDates = await _connection.Table<Job>().Where(job => (
            job.DatePerformed > startDate && job.DatePerformed < endDate)).ToListAsync();

    _jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>(jobsBetweenDates);

    JobListView.ItemsSource = _jobs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ORM for to access the database? If yes - this is simple example:

model table:

```
public class Model
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

this is example predicate:

```
 DateTime Start;
 DateTime End;
 ..... 
 (i => (i.Start > Start && i.Start < End) ||
            (i.End > Start && i.End < End))
```

Comment: Thank you FetFrumos. Although my Model class only had DatePerformed field, i was able to modify your example to make it work.